# jQuery: How To Pass $(this) As Argument To Function After It's Been Defined In Click Event

Tags: jquery, events, this, arguments

Ok, so here is the deal. I am calling this init function once. It runs through the function and it also fires my region.prototype.load(); and my region.prototype.edit(); function once. In the middle of the init function I am binding a click and touchstart event to .myElement

Here is the problem though. $ths is not defined as having a value for the region.prototype.edit(); when it first loads the functions. $ths doesn't get defined until you click on .myElement. But I need to pass $ths to another function. But I can't put region.prototype.edit(); inside the click event because it's binding events at the document level to HTML elements and if I do that, then every time I click on .myElement, another click event will be attached to an element and it basically causes recursion. So for every one click, I would have 3 or more events fire.

How could I set this up so that my region.prototype.edit() only fires once AND it only fires once after I have clicked on .myElement and defined $ths?

```
    region.prototype.init = function() {
region.prototype.load();        
var chfTxt;
var $ths;

$(document).on("click", ".myElement", function (e, $ths) {
    e.stopPropagation();        
    $ths = $(this);

    $ths.each(function () {
        var options = {
            splitScreen: true,
            titleTxt: "Test"
        }
        $ths.openPopUp(options);

        if ($ths.data("x") == "yes") {
            chfTxt = $ths.text();
            $('#thing').text(chfTxt);
            $('#thing2').addClass("selected");      
        } else if($ths.data("y") == "yes") {
            $('#thing3').addClass("selected");
        }
    });
    return $ths;
});
region.prototype.edit(compPages, chfTxt, $ths);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue.

I gave my first click a namespace like so:

```
$(document).on("click.myElement", ".myElement", function (e) {})
```

This I put my region.prototype.edit(); function inside a jQuery .one() method like so:

```
$(document).one("click", ".myElement", function (e) {
    region.prototype.edit(compPages, chfTxt, $ths);
});
```

So now they both fire on click, and $ths is being defined for my function, but my edit() function will only fire once and won't propagate.

I also removed that return call since that was horribly wrong